# iOS (Swift): How to resize the height of an UIWebView when keyboard is/not in use

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, keyboard, resize

I am trying to build a "native" Webapp for iOS because I do not really want to get to deep into the Swift matter, because I have been a Web Developer for years now and it with using the UIWebView it is quite easy to take that path.

But unfortunately I have got an issue with the size of the UIWebView. My goal is to autmatically change the height of the UIWebView when the keyboard gets en-/disabled, so that the WebView only takes the available free space on screen.

The iOS App itself is coded in Swift and I guess the right approach will be using a Keyboard Notifications (UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, UIKeyboardWillHideNotification).

I really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you can add this code on your ViewControllers inside viewDidLoad() method

```
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShowFunction:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil) //WillShow and not Did ;) The View will run animated and smooth
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHideFunction:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

You should add scrollView backround on your webView
And then you should add those two functions which are provides to get when keyboard show or hide and then you just change insets and offsets on your scrollView

```
func keyboardWillShowFunction(notification: NSNotification) {
   if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
      if let keyboardSize: CGSize =    userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue().size {
        let contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height,  0.0);
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInset
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0 + keyboardSize.height)
    }
  }
}

func keyboardWillHideFunction(notification: NSNotification) {
   if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {

      if let keyboardSize: CGSize =  userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue().size {
       let contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
       self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
       self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInset
       self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, self.scrollView.contentOffset.y)

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Heya Thank you for your help so far.
I tried the code above but it does not work in the way it is written: http://zetaneon.net/share/download/XCode.png
All those "self" statements point nowwhere (and I guess I am just to dump to implement it right).
Of cource I was already playing a bit with the code and tried to change all "self" statements with "webView". This already does have some impact, but only makes the UIWebView "spring" a bit when an input gets selected. Apart from that the size of the WebView remains unchanged.
Thanks again ;)

Comment: As additional information, because this may be an issue here:
The WebView has the size of the entire screen. This is done by contraints with a distance of 0 to all sides.